# Canon t3 screen issue

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, lcd

I have a Canon EOS Rebel T3. In auto mode it will take photos and the LCD is fine. But in other modes like P, Tv, Av or Manual, half or more of the screen is black.

If I click the photo button again it will correct itself and show the full LCD screen.Then if I turn the dial back to auto, half the LCD is black again etc.

Any idea what could be causing this? This is a new camera to me - it came with an auction I bought.

Comment: So have you reset to factory settings? Are you in live view or not? Have you looked at the shutter box for obstructions or issues? Can you take a picture of the LCD screen for us to see?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes I did clear all camera settings and custom settings in the menu.Am in live view. No sign of obstructions when I take the lens off.I took photos but first time on this site saw the tutorial but don't see a link to add photos...how do I add them?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say which half is black. If it's the bottom portion of the screen, and you are using flash, your shutter speed may be faster than the max sync speed of your camera, which is about 1/250 sec.

Comment: The bottom half is black don't think it has anything to do with shutter speed or flash the screen is 1/2 or more black on the bottom you can see live view on the upper 1/3 to 1/2 of the screen when I turn the camera on before any photos are taken.When it comes on like this if I click the photo button again to the middle right of the LCD I get a full screen live view.If I click that button again it goes back to the partial black screen.Thanks for responding